# Aligning image with multi panel ggplot2

Tags: r, image, ggplot2, tidyverse

Trying to align an image with some plots of geochem data for the data set and code below. Plot should be on the left hand column and align to the top and bottom of platted items.
Ideally it would look something like this:

[ggplot with aligned image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmqDj.jpg)

Here is a link to the [image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16JiXPYHZzAa--iZ-Ju6fMLOL4Sm1ELqe)

```
k2_xrf <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Location, ~depth, ~depth_unit, ~param, ~count, ~units,  ~age, ~units_age,
  "Kiani",     0L,   "cm",   "Si",  2984L,  "ppm", 3000L,       "BP",
  "Kiani",     2L,   "cm",   "Si",  3318L,  "ppm",    NA,         NA,
  "Kiani",     4L,   "cm",   "Si",  3296L,  "ppm",    NA,       "BP",
  "Kiani",     6L,   "cm",   "Si",  3712L,  "ppm", 5400L,       "BP",
  "Kiani",     8L,   "cm",   "Si",  4416L,  "ppm",    NA,       "BP",
  "Kiani",     0L,   "cm",    "S",  3172L,  "ppm", 3000L,       "BP",
  "Kiani",     2L,   "cm",    "S",  3411L,  "ppm",    NA,       "BP",
  "Kiani",     4L,   "cm",    "S",  3835L,  "ppm",    NA,       "BP",
  "Kiani",     6L,   "cm",    "S",  4281L,  "ppm", 5400L,       "BP",
  "Kiani",     8L,   "cm",    "S",  3896L,  "ppm",    NA,       "BP",
  "Kiani",     0L,   "cm",    "K",   325L,  "ppm", 3000L,       "BP",
  "Kiani",     2L,   "cm",    "K",    99L,  "ppm",    NA,       "BP",
  "Kiani",     4L,   "cm",    "K",   180L,  "ppm",    NA,       "BP",
  "Kiani",     6L,   "cm",    "K",   559L,  "ppm", 5400L,       "BP",
  "Kiani",     8L,   "cm",    "K",   504L,  "ppm",    NA,       "BP"
)
```

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidypaleo)

adm <- age_depth_model(depth = c(0, 6), age = c(3000, 5400))

k2_xrf %>%
  mutate(param = fct_relevel(param, "Si", "S", "K")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = count, y = depth)) +
  geom_lineh() +
  scale_y_depth_age(adm, age_breaks = c(3000, 5400)) +
  facet_geochem_gridh(vars(param))
```

Comment: You could check out the `cowplot` package and its `ggdraw`, `draw_image`, `draw_plot` functions.

Comment: Another useful package is from the patchwork library that helps align plots quite simply

Comment: Thank you, sorry I am a complete noob with R.  yes patchwork was suggested by another.  I think to use the function wrap_plots.   I think I need to create a separate image object and then I use wrap_plots to string them together?

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add cols = vars(param) to facet_grid as below. Also your code has a lot of typos in it. Make sure next time when you are pasting a code in, you review it.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidypaleo)

adm <- age_depth_model(depth = c(0, 6), age = c(3000, 5400))

k2_xrf %>%
  mutate(param = fct_relevel(param, "Si", "S", "K")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = count, y = depth)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_depth_age(adm, age_breaks = c(3000, 5400)) +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(param))
```